# Move cell contents to one column

Tags: vba, excel

I'm new to this and I've been trying to move cell contents to one column. I found a code online and it worked fine but when the sheet has more than 1000 contents, it get's an "Error 2029". Can anyone help me understand why this is happening?

The code's below:

```
    Sub MakeOneColumn()

    Dim vaCells As Variant
    Dim vOutput() As Variant
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim lRow As Long

    If TypeName(Selection) = "Range" Then
        If Selection.Count > 1 Then
            If Selection.Count <= Selection.Parent.Rows.Count Then
                vaCells = Selection.Value

                ReDim vOutput(1 To UBound(vaCells, 1) * UBound(vaCells, 2), 1 To 1)

                For j = LBound(vaCells, 2) To UBound(vaCells, 2)
                    For i = LBound(vaCells, 1) To UBound(vaCells, 1)
                        If Len(vaCells(i, j)) > 0 Then
                            lRow = lRow + 1
                            vOutput(lRow, 1) = vaCells(i, j)
                        End If
                    Next i
                Next j

                Selection.ClearContents
                Selection.Cells(1).Resize(lRow).Value = vOutput
            End If
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

It is stored in my PERSONAL.XLSB file and running it via Macros. When I run line by line in VBA Project, it's giving me an error in

`If Len(vaCells(i, j)) > 0 Then`

Indicating mismatch error.

Here's the link of the Test File.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwfUfQfWNeG5VVpIOFItcmdCSWs

Comment: Are there any error values in your selected cells?

Comment: When it errors what is the value at that position on the array `vaCells` ?

Comment: I can't really pinpoint the exact location of the error since the contents on the sheet is quite a lot. But on the Code it self it shows vaCells(i, j)=Error 2029

Comment: just wrap up your `If Len(vaCells(i, j)) > 0 Then` into an `If Not IsError(vaCells(i, j)) Then`... because error-values (like #REF or #DIV/0!) will allways break your code when going for `Len` or just a simple `<> ""`... ;)

Comment: oh... also a simple `If IsError(vaCells(i, j)) Then vaCells(i, j) = CStr(vaCells(i, j))` could avoid that (if you want to keep the error) ;)

Comment: @DirkReichel - Thank you so much! It worked! One thing though, it also moved the blank cells with to the column. Can you tell what happened there?

Comment: have you replaced the `Len(vaCells(i, j)) > 0` with `IsError(vaCells(i, j))`? it should just be a pre-check... so you will run `If Not IsError(vaCells(i, j)) Then` and **inside** that if-statement there will still be your `If Len(vaCells(i, j)) > 0 Then`

Comment: @DirkReichel - I got it now! Thanks a bunch man. You're gold!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works fine on my machine. There's no error occurs even if the column has more than 1,000 contents. I assume that you didn't change the name of your selection range properly and didn't select the selected range "Range" when the code is executed. To change the reference of a new selected range, you can edit it in menu **Formula** ► **Name Manager** in Excel 2010.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand Anastasiya. I've stored the code on my PERSONAL.xlsb file and just run it using the Macro program. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @Marco I assumed you add the data every time you run the code. But you forgot to change the new range of your data into "Range". Change the reference range of "Range" to fit your new data. After you do that, keep selecting "Range" and execute your code. Anyway, could you tell the version of your Excel?

Comment: I'm sorry if I'm a bit slow in the uptake but the data is actually as is. I'm not adding anything new to every time I run the code. When my contents are less than a thousand, it works fine but when a run this on a sheet with more than 1000 contents, that's when it starts to act up. 

I'm using Excel 2016.

Comment: @Marco Do you mind if you post your Excel file to the question so we can have a look into it? Your code didn't throw any error when I run it on my machine

Comment: @Anastasiya-Romanova秀 - TypeName() returns a string describing the type of object currently selected: if it is a Range object (and not for example a shape object, control,chart, etc) then it returns the string "Range".  It's a useful check to make if you want your code to operate on Something the user has selected, since you may get errors if something other than a Range is selected.

Comment: @TimWilliams So is your comment implying my answer is somehow correct?

Comment: @Anastasiya-Romanova秀 - I'm not sure how to do that. There's no attach option on the question.

Comment: @Marco You can send upload your file to Dropbox or Google Drive and share the download link to your question or comment

Comment: @Anastasiya-Romanova秀 - I've added the link for the test file. Thanks for your trouble about this.

Comment: @Marco I'll check after having breakfast. I hope I can be of help to you

Comment: @Anastasiya-Romanova秀  - I was commenting on your advice about using Name Manager: the OP is not using any named ranges (or if they are that's not related to their question)